# unable to see git color in Cygwin

Tags: git, bash, cygwin

I am still unable to see git output in colored format. I have all the required setting as mentioned in various SO questions.

Screen from Git:

[image]

Screen for Git Bash:
[image]

Here is my git config file

```
ashish /cygdrive/c/my-data/code/sample(integration) $ git config --list
core.symlinks=false
core.autocrlf=false
color.diff=auto
color.status=auto
color.branch=auto
color.interactive=true
pack.packsizelimit=2g
help.format=html
http.sslcainfo=/bin/curl-ca-bundle.crt
sendemail.smtpserver=/bin/msmtp.exe
diff.astextplain.textconv=astextplain
rebase.autosquash=true
http.sslverify=false
user.name=Ashish Tyagi
user.email=ashish@sample.com
diff.tool=diffmerge
difftool.diffmerge.cmd="C:\program files\sourcegear\common\diffmerge\sgdm.exe" $LOCAL $REMOTE
merge.tool=diffmerge
mergetool.diffmerge.trustexitcode=true
mergetool.diffmerge.cmd="C:\program files\sourcegear\common\diffmerge\sgdm.exe" --merge --result=$MERGED $LOCAL $BASE $REMOTE
credential.helper=store
push.default=simple
core.autocrlf=true
color.ui=auto
color.diff=auto
color.status=auto
color.branch=auto
color.interactive=auto
color.pager=true
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=false
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
core.symlinks=false
core.ignorecase=true
core.hidedotfiles=dotGitOnly
```

Comment: are you using mintty ?

Comment: and which version of git ?

Comment: git version 1.9.5.msysgit.1

Comment: @matzeri yes I am using mintty.

Comment: git version on cygwin is 2.8.3. May be you should install it. Assuming that you have cygwin installed.

Comment: @matzeri yes I have cygwin installed. How do I install additional package

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To install additional packages using the cygwin Setup

https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/setup-net.html#setup-packages

Using git as example:

```
1) select "Full" view
2) search "git" to filter between the ~ 4000 packages 
3) click on "New" column at git row the "Skip" until the "2.8.3-1" is selected
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you it fixed my issue.